# Is there a way to output each individual page generated with html2pdf/jspdf as an image?

Tags: jspdf, html2pdf

So, I'm trying to get an image output for each individual page of the pdf generated with html2pdf.

We can iterate through the pdf like this and get each page object.

```
html2pdf().from(content).set(config).toPdf().get('pdf').then((pdf) => {
    var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
            
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        console.log(pdf);
    }
           
})
```

I want to know if there is a way we can get an image output from this object?